# Google place restful api using query string not giving response on search ios

Tags: ios, web-services, google-places-api

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?input=mall&key=API_KEY

Using above API getting blank result result

Please, can anyone help for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you send request in this form you don't specify in which area you would like to find malls. Sounds like you request malls world wide. I'm afraid Google Maps Places API doesn't work this way and returns `ZERO_RESULTS`. You should provide more context to your search. Specify in which area you are searching.

For example use text like `mall, Barcelona, Spain`

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=mall%2C%20Barcelona%2C%20Spain&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Or specify location and radius to bias your results:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=mall&location=48.83920939999999%2C2.34847&radius=2000&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Both these requests return results in specified area. Also note that text search doesn't have `input` parameter it has `query` parameter.

I hope it helps!